# What does this block of varnish code do?

Tags: cache, varnish, http-caching, varnishncsa, cache-control

I have this code in varnish config and not sure what it do!
This config will cache or not my client requests? what is wrong with it?

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.status != 200) {
        return (pass);
    }
    set beresp.http.X-Backend = beresp.backend.name;


    unset beresp.http.cookie;
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;

    if (bereq.http.x-render-type == "test" && beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html") {
        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store";
    }

    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store";
    if (bereq.http.x-render-type == "test" && beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of VCL code seems to specify some rules on when to bypass the cache. However, the way it is written doesn't make a lot of sense.

### Bypassing the cache

`return(pass)` is not the proper way of bypassing the caching in the `vcl_backend_response` context. `return(pass)` is used in `vcl_recv` when an incoming request bypasses the cache.

In `vcl_backend_response` bypassing the cache means preventing from storing the incoming object in the cache. The best practices dictate that you do `set beresp.uncacheable = true`, assign a TTL and then `return(deliver)`. This ensures that this object bypasses the cache for a certain amount of time until the next backend response meets the required criteria.

My enabling `beresp.uncacheable`, you're ensuring that the object ends up on the waiting list and becomes a candidate for request coalescing.

### Removing cookies

Removing cookies often makes sense to improve your hit rate. In the backend context you will remove the `Set-Cookie` header. This is correctly done in `vcl_backend_response` through `unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie`, however this is done unconditionally.

This means that any `Set-Cookie` action will not take place, which could result in inconsistent behavior. Not sure if pre-conditions are required for the removal of these cookies.

You can also remove incoming cookies through `unset req.http.Cookie`. But there seems to be a similar call in `vcl_backend_response` that runs `unset beresp.http.Cookie`.

This would indicate that a `Cookie` response header would be received. That seems unlikely.

### Rewriting the VCL

This is how I would rewrite this VCL code without any other context:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(beresp.status != 200) {
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return(deliver);
    }

    set beresp.http.X-Backend = beresp.backend.name;
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store";

    if (bereq.http.x-render-type == "test" && beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html") {
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return(deliver);
    }

    return (deliver);
}
```

> Warning: I would not recommend copy/pasting this could into your production environment. I have a feeling that some corners were cut when writing this VCL. Since I don't have any additional context, I don't want to advise using this.